# Email Validation - Regular Expression

Tags: asp.net, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

Does anyone have a good email regular expression? I'm writing in .NET 2.0 if that matters...

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses