# regular expression to find email addresses from specific domain

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate the e-mail address entered by the user that it is like that format `anything@iti.gov.eg`. `iti.gov.eg` must be writen in the e-mail address. The user must enter his e-mail address in that format in text box.

And how can I retrive it from the text box and check it?

My code is:

```
var r=/^([a-z\.])+\@(iti)+\.+(gov)+\.+(eg)+$/;
if (!r.test(string))
    alert("the email is not correct");
else 
    alert("your email is correct");
```

But this is wrong. Can any one help me please?

Comment: Why not have `\.iti\.gov\.eg`?

Comment: If your user's emails must end with "@iti.gov.eg" - why not simply ask them to enter only their user name part? Then simply append "@iti.gov.eg" to what ever they type. It will save user's the trouble of typing and you the trouble of complex regex.

Answer (score 3):

See this question on how to validate an email using regular expressions in JavaScript:

[Validate email address in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Once you know that it is a valid email address you can then check to make sure that it contains the string `@iti.gov.eg` (case insensitive) which is a much easier task.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is wrong because `anything@itiiti.govgov.egeg` will be matched. As the `+` means once or more.

You only need `/^[a-z.]+@iti\.gov\.eg$/`.

Comment: I didn't copy your answer, just been tooooo slow :)

Comment: @dwo: it always happens in simple questions like this :)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the dots in a regex: you write .+ which means 1 to n random characters. I think you meant:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)@iti\.gov\.eg$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 /^[a-z][\w.+-]+@iti\.gov\.eg$/
```

This regex ensures that the name part starts with a letter. `.`, `+`, `-` etc are valid characters in an email.

And yeah, [email validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903356/email-validation-regular-expression/1903368#1903368) is a tricky thing.