# NulltoString eq in C#

Tags: c#

I have this method to validate email addresses:

```
public static bool isEmail(string inputEmail)
{
    inputEmail = NulltoString(inputEmail);
    string strRegex = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
                      @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" +
                      @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$";
    Regex re = new Regex(strRegex);
    if (re.IsMatch(inputEmail))
        return (true);
    else
        return (false);
}
```

But I get the error: `The name 'NulltoString' does not exist in the current context`.

Is there a `string` method that is equivalent to `NulltoString()`?

Comment: There is no such thing as NulltoString. What did you expect?

Comment: Your method is wrong.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903356/email-validation-regular-expression/1903368#1903368

Comment: At the very least, you shouldn't parse the regex every time you call the method.

Comment: @John Cromartie - Why do you think I asked the question?

Comment: @SsRide360 - I think John was wondering why you would ask for an equivalent to something called `NulltoString` without explaining what `NulltoString` is or how you would expect it to behave if it did exist.

Comment: Ahh. I just saw a method with `NulltoString` in it so I assumed that it was some really really old deprecated method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C# language already has a good feature for this, the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
inputEmail = inputEmail ?? string.Empty;
```

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr: I'm just here to help, learn and get score some points ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following:

`inputEmail = inputEmail ?? String.Empty;`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
 public static bool isEmail(string inputEmail)
{
    inputEmail = inputEmail?? string.Empty;
    string strRegex = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
          @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" +
          @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$";
    Regex re = new Regex(strRegex);
    if (re.IsMatch(inputEmail))
        return (true);
    else
        return (false);
}
```

More efficient than that:

```
     if (null == inputEmail)
         return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputEmail))
    //throw exception
```