# How well does Stack Overflow's own e-mail validation regex work?

Tags: javascript, email-validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

I found this e-mail validation regular expression in Stack Overflow's own answer page code. Is it valid/effective?

```
function saveEmailNotification(email) {
    // only post if the email is valid
    if (!(/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i).test(email)) return;
...
}
```

Comment: (reads regex) Yep! Have you tested it?

Comment: it passed basic validation ! But as i'm not able to read regex i dont know what the code actually means :(

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903356/email-validation-regular-expression/1903368#1903368

Comment: @Sourav, do you think I do? I can't read regex, as I'm human.

Comment: @Matt that was perhaps the longest regex :O in the world

Comment: my question was IS IT A GOOD ONE, WHAT IT DOES ACTUALLY !

Comment: Another punch in the face for those poor people @ .museum

Comment: @Sourav: No, it's not a good one; this is several kinds of broken. info@example.भारत  might be a valid e-mail address, yet it fails your test. What it does is takes valid e-mail addresses and rejects them; you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Then why SO still use it :? Is it for fooling people :x

Comment: @Sourav: This is SO code?!? o_O I'm shocked, *shocked*! I will be asking the same question.

Comment: @Piskvor Yup, in a function called `function saveEmailNotification` , and thats the reason i asked here, people are closing the question :( HELP !!!

Comment: It looks like this function is actually not used when setting email notifications, but is indeed hanging there in the source code.

Comment: See me rant, all righteously indignant and foaming at the mouth, in the "Letters to editor" section: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92094/false-negatives-when-validating-notification-e-mails-widespread-sloppy-coding-e (in other words, I added this as a bug on Meta)

Comment: Update: It is being used (check by tracking XHR requests in Chrome Dev Tools).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to re-invent the wheel. From jQuery validation (see http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/):

```
function validateEmail(value){return /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i.test(value);}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i
```

`^` means start of the string

`[A-Z0-9._%+-]+` means: one or more of these characters

`@` means a @ should come now

`[A-Z0-9.-]+` means: one or more of these characters

`\.` means a . should come now

`[A-Z]{2,4}` means: 2, 3 or 4 letters

`$` means end of string

`i` is a flag indicating it accepts both lowercase and uppercase.

Comment: @Sourav: yes, they do; plus they support various other characters like `[{}]` etc.

Comment: google,yahoo still says `Only letters, numbers, underscores, and one dot (.) are allowed`

Comment: @Sourav: ...when choosing your username __at those providers__. Google isn't the whole world (yet ;)).

Comment: Google, hotmail, yahoo, rediff i think the list is complete :P

Comment: @Sourav: Add Facebook and it is :D

Answer (score 1):

You really should use RFC-822 compliant regexp instead - http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: btw who coded that thing ? was it bill or mark or steve ? :O :0

Comment: @Sourav, according to the [credits](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address/Mail-RFC822-Address.html#credits) name is Abigail

Comment: i was just joking :), but thats a realllllllllllllllly huge code !

Comment: @Sourav: None of those three are particularly great programmers, despite being successful businesmen, should you mean Gates, Zuckerberg and Jobs.

Comment: @Piskvor Yup, but i think Bill is/was a good programmer :)