# Regex validation for ordering domains

Tags: javascript, regex

my friends,
I would like to ask you for help with my regex requirements. I need regex validation for domains based on the conventions for the client in JS:

- 63 characters. The 63 characters does not include what is referred to as the protocol identifier https:// or the domain extension (such as .com or .org on a subdomain)
- no hyphen on the start and end of the string but it can be used in domains like text-example.com
- no special characters are allowed
- periods can be used when registering domain name however periods can be utilize in subdomains
- domains can have numbers
- client can provide multiple domains separated with semicolons - each domain should be validated separately

In the beginning, I thought it will be ok to have a separate regex for every point but I think it will time consuming operation. Could some help me with topic?

Answer (score 0):

My answer to the question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449367/c-sharp-email-address-validation/6459786" might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6459786/467473

It implements an email address validator in C#. You don't care about the "local part" (the bit left of the `@` in email addresses, or the `@` itself. The bit that's interesting to you is the `fqdn` production and that should be fairly straightforward to map to a Javascript regular expression.

On further consideration, it does sound like what you are describing is a DNS ***label***, a single segment of a DNS name.

If what you want is to validate an RFC-compliant DNS label, then this regula expression ought to do you:

```js
const rxDnsLabel = /^[A-Z]([A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?$/i;
```

Breaking it down:

- `^` — anchors the start of the match to start-of-text, followed by
- `[A-Z]` — a US-ASCII letter, followed by
- `(` — an optional group, consisting of

  - `[A-Z0-9-]` — a US-ASCII letter, decimal digit or hyphen (`-`)

    - `{0,61}` — repeated 0 to 61 times, followed by
  - `[A-Z0-9]` a single US-ASCII letter or decimal digit
- `)?` — the whole of which is optional
- `$` — anchors the end of the match to end-of-text

If you need to match a DNS name consisting of multiple labels, it's not that much more complicated. Just need to allow the optional extra segments:

```js
const rxDnsLabel = /^([A-Z]([A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?)([.][A-Z]([A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?)*$/i;
```

The only difference here is that the initial label is allowed to be followed by zero or more additional labels, each separated with a period/full stop ( `.`).

**Edited to note:** If you require support for internationalized (punycode) domain names, I can't guarantee that this will match them
mostly because I never needed to do so, and so haven't tested this against them. For details on internationalized (punycode) domain names, see the relevant RFs:

- [RFC 3492: *Punycode: A Bootstring encoding of Unicode for Internationalized Domain Names in Applications (IDNA)*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/pdfrfc/rfc3492.txt.pdf)
- [RFC 5891: *Internationalized Domain Names in Applications (IDNA): Protocol*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/pdfrfc/rfc5891.txt.pdf