# Adding capital letters in php email validation

Tags: php

I have used this pregmatch statement for validating email address

`preg_match("^[a-z0-9_\+-]+(\.[a-z0-9_\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.([a-z]{2,4})$^", $partner_email)`

If i use capital letters it will show an error.How i can change the pregmatch condition for supporting capital letters in email addres
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your regex is wrong.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903356/email-validation-regular-expression/1903368#1903368

Comment: You should have a look at [this thread][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

several ways:

1) change [a-z0-9_+-] to [a-zA-Z0-9_+] in all places

2) use preg_match("/^...$/i", $partner_emal) ... the /i flag makes it case-insensitive

3) use strtolower($partner_email) as the match string.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve it by adding `i` flag after the delimiter or as fourth parameter to [preg_match()](http://bg.php.net/preg_match)

Comment: The fourth parameter of preg_match doesn't take that kind of flag. Those flags are specific to how it returns the matched data when dealing with string captures.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to just insist that the string is lower-case. This is probably preferable to mucking with (and perhaps debugging) a regex that you did not write and is known to work.

```
preg_match("^[a-z0-9_\+-]+(\.[a-z0-9_\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.([a-z]{2,4})$^", strtolower($partner_email))
```

Answer (score -1):

Swap a-z for a-Z

10morechars....

Comment: That's backwards, as it should be A-z. But beyond that, that also includes the characters [ \ ] ^ _ `, which are between the A-Z and a-z in the character range.