# form validation self study

Tags: javascript

please help. I'm not asking you to create the program just please tell me what I'm missing. This is for self studying. I am trying to make a javascript program that would do this:
    1. alert user if no name or email had been created
    2. email data must contain an @ sign and at least one dot (.). Also, the @ must not be the first character of the email address, and the last dot must be present after the @ sign, and minimum 2 characters before the end.
 My code:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function validateForm1()
 {
 var y=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
 var atpos=y.indexOf("@");
 var dotpos=y.lastIndexOf(".");
 var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
 if (x==null || x=="" ||  y=="")
 {
 alert("First name and Email must be filled out");
 return false;
 }
 else if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)

 {
 alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
 return false;
}
}

 </script>
 </head>

 <body>

<form name="myForm" action=# onsubmit="return validateForm1()" method="post">
 First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br/>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your else if condition, it should be `dotpos + 2 >= y.length` instead of `dotpos + 2 >=x.length`

Comment: also as numbers1311407 and Farhan suggested, better use regular expression for email address validation

Answer (score 0):

To check to see if the fields are not empty, you can simply use this:

```
if (strValue) {
    // string not empty
} else {
    // string empty
}
```

If you need to check specifically for an empty string over null, I would think checking against `""` is your best bet, using the `===` operator (so that you know that it is, in fact, a string you're comparing against).

For validating the email address, I would suggest using a regular expression.

Here is an example:

```
function validateEmail(elementValue){
   var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
   return emailPattern.test(elementValue);
}
```

Comment: Here's a [better example of an email regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903356/email-validation-regular-expression)...it'll blow your mind!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than coming up with your own rules for email, consider that emails all adhere to a regular format, making them a good candidate for regular expressions.

This is the first email regex I found with google (meaning there may very well be better ones).

```
var email_rx = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
```

This greatly simplifies your code.  No more looking for dots and ampersands, you simply check that the email matches the supplied regex pattern:

```
function validateForm1() {
  var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
  var fname = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;

  // also note that in javascript, empty strings and nulls are both "falsey",
  // so this conditional works.
  if (!fname || !email) {
    alert("First name and Email must be filled out");
    return false;

  // if they both exist, test your email versus the regex.
  } else if (!email_rx.test(email)) {
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
> function validateForm1()    > {    >   var y=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
```

You should be careful of long property access chains, if a part is missing you'll simply get an error and the script will cease functioning. Also, use sensible names for variables, it makes life much easier. Consider something like:

```
  var form = document.forms['myForm'];
  var emailInput = form && form.elements['email'];
  var email = emailInput && emailInput.value;
```

Now if the form or email input are missing for whatever reason, you have a much better chance of dealing with the error and not just crashing the script.

```
>   var atpos=y.indexOf("@");    >   var dotpos=y.lastIndexOf(".");
```

Your requirement for the email address (which is quite minimal and likely of not much use, but that's your choice) can be met by a regular expression:

```
  var emailRe = /.+@.*\...+$/;

>   var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
>   if (x==null || x=="" ||  y=="")
```

If you initialise *x* (which I'll call *name*) similarly to *y* (which I renamed *email*), then *x* will either be undefined or a string. Presumably you want the name to not be empty and not have only white space, so:

```
  var nameRe = /^\s*$/;  // match string of just zero or more whitespace characters
  if (name && nameRe.test) {
```

.

```
>   {
>     alert("First name and Email must be filled out");
>     return false;
>   }
>   else if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
```

And that can be:

```
  else if (!emailRe.test(email)) {
```

.

```
>   {
>     alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
>     return false;
>    }
>  }
```