# Email Validation Javascript Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Good Evening, 
I am working on creating a regular expression to validate email addresses in Javascript. I have the function working, however I know this expression could be written better. How could I improve it?

```
function checkEmailAddress(inputEmailAddy){
    var regex = new RegExp(\"^([A-Z][a-z][0-9][_][-][.])+\@([A-Z][a-z][0-9][_][-][.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/\");

    return (regex.test(inputEmailAddy) == 1 ? 1 : -1);
}
```

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Maybe: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585

Comment: The quintessential email address regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903356/email-validation-regular-expression

Comment: This has been asked many times, try this search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Email+address+validation+regex&submit=search

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

Comment: Regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 2):

The local-part of the email, to the left of the `@` sign, can contain *absolutely **anything*** if quoted properly, and you simply cannot interpret quoting with a regular expression - you *must* parse the email address according to RFC rules, or you ***will*** reject some valid email addresses.

Even with a regex that is "good enough" you still have to send a confirmation email to verify that it's a legitimate address.

(most of the answers suggested here on SO to the many times this question has been asked will fail, and reject my email address, because I have a plus `+` my address)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this one in [PHP's eregi](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) (i know it's deprecated):

```
'^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_\.\-]*@[a-z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$'
```

I quickly changed it to work in JS:

```
/^[a-z][a-z0-9_\.\-]*@[a-z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i
```

Quick check:

```
var r = /^[a-z][a-z0-9_\.\-]*@[a-z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i;

r.test('someone@somesite.com'); // true
r.test('xyz@xyz.xyz'); // true
r.test('abc@3'); // false
r.test('xyz'); // false
r.test('asdf@asdf.asdfasdfasdf'); // false
```

One gotchya is that I'm using `{2,4}` for the last part, so it matches things like `.net` and `.com`. But it won't match valid ones like `.museum` while it will match non-existant ones like `.xx`

Now, just for the lulz, I've crated a regexp similar to the one above but instead of the `[a-z]{2,4}` I set it up to match every valid domain I am aware of:

```
/^[a-z][a-z0-9_\.\-]*@[a-z0-9\.\-]+\.(?:aero|asia|biz|cat|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|net|org|pro|tel|travel|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|xxx|ye|yt|za|zm|zw)$/i
```

giving you:

```
r.test('someone@somesite.com'); // true
r.test('someone@somefakesite.xb'); // false
r.test('asdf'); // false
r.test('.museum'); // false
r.test('someone@somemuseumsite.museum'); // true
```

This, of course, makes for a crazy long regexp and (if you want it to hold up over time) will have to be maintained.

Also, in all of these cases, some valid (but very uncommon) addresses will fail. Something like `somebody@[192.168.2.1]`

Comment: It would also reject **my** email address, which has a `+` in it. See the monstrosity mentioned in the answer referenced by Clive's comment to the question.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that looks way crazier yet better.

Comment: Considering that now everyone with enough money can buy new top domain level, hard-coding top-domain level in a regex is a quite bad idea. You're almost guaranteed that it will be wrong in the future.

Comment: thats why is said 'for the lulz' - just showing how overboard a regexp for email can be.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example code

```
<input type="text" id="email">
function test(){
var emailElement = document.getElementById('#email');
var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9_\-])+([\.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\@((([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.){1,2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,40})$/;

if(!emailPattern(emailElement.value)){
    return false;
   } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```