# Using REGEX for email

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, email-validation

I have been trying to use this regex for email in javascript but i can not seem to find one that actually works! I just need to take out all special characters that would not be needed for an email address (< > ? /  | [ ] { } ( ) * & ^ % $ # ! ~ ` 'space', etc..)

```
function validateForOnlyEmail(txt) { txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}]+/g, ''); }
```

Thanks!

**update**

Ok, how would i just block those special characters above using RegEX?

Comment: I think most (if not all) of those characters you mentioned are valid in email addresses - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address#RFC_specification

Comment: Update - you **shouldn't** be blocking !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~

Comment: @StealthRT Y dnt you block those characters at `keypress` itself...`blocking` and `replacing` those special characters above using `RegEX` doesn't make **sense**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to validate an Email Address **Regex** is not the right choice..

Use [MailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx) as recommended by our own **geek** [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903356/email-validation-regular-expression/1903368#1903368)

```
try 
{
   address = new MailAddress(address).Address;
} 
catch(FormatException) 
{
   //address is invalid
}
```

Comment: +1 Agree regex is not the solution: Here is some sample regex to validate an email address http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: I have to disagree about this as a solution for a couple of reasons. First, this is a server side solution whereas the request was for a JavaScript solution. Secondly, from a lot of experience using the MailAddress object it is quite poor at allowing through it invalid email addresses as well as rejecting valid email addresses. If you are using System.Net.Mail to send the emails then it is a moot point but this is not a fool proof way of validating email addresses.

Comment: @rrr `Regex` is also not a fool proof way to do!