# Regex not matching

Tags: c#, regex, validation, email-validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)
>   [Email Validation - Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903356/email-validation-regular-expression)

I am using following code to validate Email address in C#, but not sure why it fails always:

```
 var regEx = @"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})";

        if (Regex.IsMatch(regEx, "abcde@gmail.com", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
```

Please can someone point out what I am missing here ?

Comment: [regexp-based address validation](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The question is not "how to validate an email address", it is "why does this (already defined) regex not match".

Comment: I am not sure why the question was closed. I had an issue that why regex is not working and answer was incorrect format used plus using var to declare instead of string. I did not ask for regular expression pattern !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your [`IsMatch` parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktzf2d23.aspx) the wrong way around; the first is the input, the second is the pattern.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I noticed that and modified my code, but still I get error. The best overload method match for System.text.regularexpression.regex.ismatch(string, int) has invalid arguments.

Comment: You should have `Regex.IsMatch("abcde@gmail.com", regEx, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)` - is that what you have now?

Comment: I had assigned pattern to var regEx in modified code, instead of String. It is working now. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[Test]
public void EmailTest()
{
    var pattern = @"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})";
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var address = "abcde@gmail.com";
    Assert.IsTrue(Regex.IsMatch(address, pattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
    Assert.IsTrue(regex.IsMatch(address));
}
```

You have the wrong order of string and pattern.

Also check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: Both reg expressions are same................. RMN uploaded same thing check once

Comment: @Johan - I should reference which dll for Assert ?

Comment: I use [nUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) but ms test has the same syntax. Note that the test is just an easy way to assert that it works compared to writing a console app or something.

Comment: @Johan- test also needs a reference.

Comment: Ok, sry. Reference nunit.framework.dll and using NUnit.Framework;
Maybe it is confusing but in the test the match is done in two ways.