# MVC3 regular expression for email

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the follwoing regular expression for email validation

```
@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$"
```

Bit it accepts **[]name@gmail.com[][]** as a valid email.whats the pattern i should use?
Is it possible to check that at client side?

Comment: [I Knew How To Validate An Email Address Until I Read The RFC](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx)

Comment: Did you try to search a little on the subject before posting your question?

Comment: Dear @YannickBlondeau I tried a lot but when i entered before or later valid email address it accepts as a valid email

Comment: possible duplicate of [Email Validation - Regular Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903356/email-validation-regular-expression)

Comment: @Amol, I meant searching on StackOverflow to see if your question has already been answered...

Comment: @YannickBlondeau yes but none of regex solve my problem i want this problem solve at client side to avoid user headac that after submit he knows that entered email address is wrong

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to validate an Email Address **Regex** is not the right choice.

Use [MailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx) as recommended by [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903356/email-validation-regular-expression/1903368#1903368)

```
try 
{
   address = new MailAddress(address).Address;
   //address is valid here
} 
catch(FormatException) 
{
   //address is invalid
}
```

---

But if you are addicted to regex..just do this

```
.*@.*
```

Comment: Hello, is it possible to check at client side?

Comment: @Amol not possible since there are many corner cases where the regex would fail..you can try `.*@.*` at client side and then check it through `MailAddress` at server side..